# Problems using random function in where clause

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to use the RANDOM function to select random rows from a table.

What I'm trying to do is that rows with category 1 has 50 % chance of being selected while rows with category 2 has 25 % chance of being selected.

In my test database I have only three records in table1. They are joined with table 2 to get category.

All three records have category 1.

If I run the following SQL

```
SELECT T2.category, T1.*
FROM table1 T1 
LEFT JOIN table2 T2 ON T1.id=T2.id
WHERE 
  ( T2.category=1 AND (TRUNC(RANDOM() * 100 ) < 50) ) OR
  ( T2.category=2 AND (TRUNC(RANDOM() * 100 ) < 25) )
```

I always get either zero or all 3 records. If I remove the last line, so that the SQL looks like this

```
SELECT T2.category, T1.*
FROM table1 T1 
LEFT JOIN table2 T2 ON T1.id=T2.id
WHERE 
( T2.category=1 AND (TRUNC(RANDOM() * 100 ) < 50) )
)
```

Everything works as expected. The records appear randomly (I sometimes get 0,1,2 or 3 records), but then of course I cannot make a distinction of chance of being selected based on category.

Why is that? I don't understand that the line I removed can influence the number of records returned as all my records are category 1 (and the line I removed was category=2)

Comment: I can not reproduce. Post sample data.